# Getting $\frac{1}{f^{-1}(y)}$ instead of $f^{-1}(y)$ for inverse of a function $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am given that the inverse of a function $f:(-1, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$,  $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x^2}$ is $$f^{-1}(y) = \frac{2y}{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4y^2}}$$

However that is not what I get when I calculate the inverse of it.

$f(x) = y = \frac{x}{1-x^2}$

$y - yx^2 = x$

$-yx^2 -x + y = 0$

$yx^2 + x - y = 0$

Then by the quadratic equation we have that

$$x =  \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4y^2}}{2y}$$

Which is $\frac{1}{f^{-1}(y)}$ for the $f^{-1}(y)$ given above.

Comment: Have you tried checking that $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$?

Comment: Multiply the Nr. of your answer by its conjugate and you will get the given answer

Comment: How do you know to multiply by the conjugate?

Answer (score 3):

Note that you aren't getting $\frac{1}{f^{-1}(y)}$ because of the $-$ sign on $1$ and the $\pm$ sign.

Since $x>-1$, we can conclude that the $\pm$ sign must be a $+$, so
$$\begin{align}
x &=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}{2y}\\
&=\frac{(-1+\sqrt{1+4y^2})(1+\sqrt{1+4y^2})}{2y(1+\sqrt{1+4y^2})}\\
&=\frac{4y^2}{2y(1+\sqrt{1+4y^2})}\\
&=\frac{2y}{1+\sqrt{1+4y^2}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: The lesson here is essentially that just because two expressions look different, doesn't mean they are.